# Error generating functions metadata because of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions, Version=3.0.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-functions

After migrating to Azure Functions V3 cannot compile and run project anymore

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Create new HTTP Trigger function
2. Update project and include
   reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.App `<ItemGroup>
   <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
   </ItemGroup>`
3. Compile project

**Stack Trace**

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' at System.Signature.GetSignature(Void* pCorSig, Int32 cCorSig, RuntimeFieldHandleInternal fieldHandle, IRuntimeMethodInfo methodHandle, RuntimeType declaringType) at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.FetchNonReturnParameters() at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.GetParameters() at MakeFunctionJson.MethodInfoExtensions.GetDisabled(MethodInfo method) at MakeFunctionJson.MethodInfoExtensions.HasUnsuportedAttributes(MethodInfo method, String& error) 
>   at MakeFunctionJson.FunctionJsonConverter.GenerateFunctions(IEnumerable1 types)+MoveNext()at System.Collections.Generic.List 1.AddEnumerable(IEnumerable1 enumerable)
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable1 source) at MakeFunctionJson.FunctionJsonConverter.TryGenerateFunctionJsons() at MakeFunctionJson.FunctionJsonConverter.TryRun()`

This also happens when reference project that has ASP.Net Core 3 framework reference

This question has been asked at https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/339 and has had no response since 7 days ago, anyone with any suggestions/workarounds?

Comment: Firstly how did you create the v3 function, make sure your v3 function working correctly, secondly which version you are using, Is the [preview one](https://dotnet.myget.org/feed/aspnetcore-dev/package/nuget/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions) cause in the nuget management I could not find the 3.0 version.

Comment: @GeorgeChen i created the v3 function this way :: https://dev.to/azure/develop-azure-functions-using-net-core-3-0-gcm

Comment: I test with this way and the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions` package in `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` is 2.1.0, so did you install the v3 and use it or just use the default .

Comment: maybe you could try set with this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntQ0C.png).Launch: Executable.Executable: {full path of .NET Core CLI’s dotnet.exe, ex. C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe} Application Arguments: {full path of the Azure Functions CLI assembly you want to run, ex. C:\Users\SomeUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\Azure.Functions.Cli.dll} host start Working Directory: {full path of your project’s build output folder, ..\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0}

Comment: This problem exists from version 2.0, so maybe you could have a try this way.

Comment: @GeorgeChen regarding https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntQ0C.png, am on ubuntu and using VS code

Comment: `func --version` == 3.0.1740

Comment: It should be `launchsettings.json` file. https://i.stack.imgur.com/1P6b7.png

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Comment: azure functions team is working on it, no timelines though, see: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/339#issuecomment-547130294

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug that was resolved, see:

[I tried Entity Framework Core 3 (netstandard2.1) with Azure Functions v3 (netcoreapp3.0), an error occurred in Metadata Generator. #349](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/349)

[Error generating functions metadata because of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions, Version=3.0.0.0 #339](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/339)